# Procedure with cursor to auto fill a column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table called **holidays** as below

```
date       |hol_name            |hol_id
-----------------------------------------
 01-01-2011|New Year's Day      |1     
02-01-2011 |Substitute Bank Hol |2           |2
```

and another table **Date** which has all dates of 2011

```
date_id|Date      |is_holiday
------------------------------
221    |01-01-2011|  
222    |02-02-2011| 
223    |03-01-2011|
224    |04-01-2011|
```

I want to create a procedure to auto populate the column **is_holiday** with a cursor which will use **holidays** as a look up and then populate **Y** if the date is a holiday and **N** if its not. I am just a bit confused how to go about it. Is it better to create a function which returns a 0 or 1 and then use that in the procedure to auto fill? that is, if it returns 1 then the cursor will insert Y and if it returns 0 it will insert N. Please point me to the right direction

Answer (score 2):

you could remove the column is_holiday from your table and create a view like

```
select d.date_id, d.date, nvl2(h.hol_id,'Y','N') as is_holiday 
    from date d left join holidays h on d.date = h.date;
```

This way it will always be up to date.

But I would rename table_name and column_name from DATE to something else to avoid any problem. date is a reserved word.

Otherwise, a simple update is sufficient.

```
update date du set is_holidays = (select nvl2(h.date,'Y','N') from date d left join holidays h on d.date = h.date where d.date = du.date);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create a procedure to auto populate the column is_holiday

That could be done using a `TRIGGER` like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_holiday BEFORE
UPDATE OR INSERT ON DATES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(CASE 
                WHEN date_t = :NEW.date_t
                    THEN 'Y'
                ELSE 'N'
                END)
    INTO :NEW.is_holiday
    FROM holidays;
END;
/
```

Note that `Date` is a keyword and shouldn't be used for table names and column names.

If you want it through a `procedure` as you've mentioned, you could run `MERGE INTO`  within your procedure.

```
MERGE INTO DATES t
USING (
    SELECT d.date_id
        ,d.date_t
        ,CASE 
            WHEN h.date_t IS NULL
                THEN 'N'
            ELSE 'Y'
            END AS is_holiday
    FROM dates d
    LEFT JOIN holidays h ON d.date_t = h.date_t
    ) s
    ON (t.date_id = s.date_id)
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
        UPDATE
        SET t.is_holiday = s.is_holiday;
```

Or these two updates

```
UPDATE Dates d
SET IS_HOLIDAY = 'Y' WHERE EXISTS ( 
                     select 1 FROM holidays  h where h.date_t = d.date_t );

UPDATE Dates d
SET IS_HOLIDAY = 'N' WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
                     select 1 FROM holidays  h where h.date_t = d.date_t );
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d07e2/2)

Comment: Thank you. Trigger seems to be a great option.I will try that

Comment: You'd also need a trigger on the holidays trigger to update the dates table when a new holiday is added.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a stored procedure because you can create a view based on below query.

```
create view dbo.dates_vw (date_id, dte,is_holiday)
as
  select d.date_id, d.dte,
  case when h.dte is null
    then 'N' else 'Y' end as is_holiday
  from dates d
 left join holidays h
 on d.dte=h.dte;
```